# Refreshing a WordPress Page using JavaScript

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a custom cart for a website, and i am still a beginner.
I am using Wordpress/woocommerce functions to add or delete from the cart, but after submiting my changes i want the page to be refreshed so i used javascript to do that.

```
location.reload();
```

however this is taking me back to the home page but with a url having the item id that i deleted from the cart.

is there a better way to refresh wordpress pages, or should location.reload() make no issues?

this is a php snippet of how i am deleting an item, i am also concerned that this snippet is responsible for taking me back to the homepage

```
$prod_to_remove = $values[product_id];

// Cycle through each product in the cart
foreach ( $WC->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

    // Get the Variation or Product ID
    $prod_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

    // Check to see if IDs match
    if( $prod_to_remove == $prod_id ) {
        $WC->cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key,$cart_item['quantity'] -1,true);
        break;
    }
}
```

any insight over the issue is appreciated, thanks in advance

Link not clear in the comments but this is how the URL is being redirected

```
http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/cart/basket.php?r=1&id=2838023a778dfaecdc212708f721b788
```

Comment: Can you give an example of URL?

Comment: why would you want to refresh the page? is submitting the page don't cause the page to refresh or something?

Comment: @DavidBallester the URL is being returned as such: http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/cart/basket.php?r=1&id=2838023a778dfaecdc212708f721b788

Comment: The page you want to reload, is it obtained through a GET or a POST (ie. you get there after submitting a form?)?